# How do I transcribe this WeChat snippet? (Characters identified: 你我当年)

Tags: character-identification

[image]

Can someone convert this Chinese snippet into copyable TEXT so I can copy it. Thank you! I’ve been having hard time searching the characters on the internet

Comment: It is 你我当年, meaning 'you and I that year'

Comment: You need an OCR app

Comment: To future readers, please see [How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say)

Answer (score 1):

That's the answer, but body must be at least 30 characters... 
你我当年

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn’t expect the response would be fast. Thank you again 

Comment: You're welcome =)

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is about. This is a correct answer.